# Identity Server 4 /connect/token return 400 Bad Request when using grant_type:authorization_code

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, .net-core-3.1

I have setup an Identity Server 4 App. Trying to set an angular client app.
Able to access provider login page and login successfully, after getting the Authorization code when, angular app calling `/connect/token` api, getting 400 Bad Request. Tested with Postman, it is working when using

```
grant_type:client_credentials
```

Information

https://localhost:5001/connect/token

```
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:angular_app_client_id
code_verifier:C0.731426161751518815973254dfd6715973254680670.9347059398232558
code:oSEydAywPs_zg4MRwbqwH-ly8ToWdrtexTDgx0ee7eY
redirect_uri:http://localhost:4200/callback
client_secret:<secret>
require_pkce:false
requried_client_secret:false
```

OpenIdConfiguration in angular app

```
const openIdConfiguration: OpenIdConfiguration = {
    stsServer: this.authUrl,
    redirect_url: this.originUrl + 'callback',
    client_id: 'demo_client_id',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid profile',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: this.originUrl,
    forbidden_route: '/forbidden',
    unauthorized_route: '/unauthorized',
    silent_renew: true,
    silent_renew_url: this.originUrl + '/silent-renew.html',
    history_cleanup_off: true,
    auto_userinfo: true,
    log_console_warning_active: true,
    log_console_debug_active: true,
    max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds: 10,
};
```

Postman Request
[image]

Server Log

```
{"ClientId": "angular_app_client_id", "Category": "Authentication", "Name": "Client Authentication Failure", "EventType": "Failure", "Id": 1011, "Message": "Invalid client secret", "ActivityId": "0HM1VK1OS0MDK:00000001", "TimeStamp": "2020-08-13T16:29:52.0000000Z", "ProcessId": 2002, "LocalIpAddress": "::1:5001", "RemoteIpAddress": "::1", "$type": "ClientAuthenticationFailureEvent"}
```

Working when grant_type is `client_credentials`
[image]

Please help...

Comment: What error do you get in the identity server logs?

Comment: Client secret validation failed for client: angular_app_client_id.

Comment: @Ravi whats ur client config on IdentityServer? can you post the code? It should be inside Config.cs class if you dont use DB

Comment: @nahidf Client config is in db

client_id = angular_app_client_id, client_name = Angular App, grant_type = client_credentials, authorization_code, client_secret = <secret>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your angular client app is an interactive app, and you need to set [`RequireClientSecret`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/Entities/Client.cs#L20) to false for it.
- Remove `client_secret` from client app and any call to IdentityServer
- And also you need to use code grant not client authorization grant for interactive apps

  - After this change ur client config in DB should look like this:

```
client_id = angular_app_client_id, client_name = Angular App, grant_type = authorization_code
```

- Note that I removed secret and also `client_credentials` as this grant is not to use for spa apps
- Set (`RequirePkce`)[https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/Entities/Client.cs#L29] to true on client config - ur case in DB
- set `response_type: "code"` on js client

  - Here is an example of how ur js client code should look like

```
var config = {
    authority: "http://localhost:5000",
    client_id: "jsclient",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    response_type: "code",
    scope:"openid profile",
    post_logout_redirect_uri : "http://localhost:5003/index.html",
};
```

- You also need to set `AllowedCorsOrigins` for the SPA app to be the apps URL. This is cause its called from browser.

I have a full working sample [here](https://github.com/nahidf/IdentityServer4-adventures/tree/ids4-4) feel free to check it out

Read more about how to set up interactive apps [Here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html?highlight=RequireClientSecret#interactive-clients)

Comment: yeah did that but still not working, "Error": "invalid_grant" | "Name": "Token Issued Failure"

Comment: I added more details on response for u @Ravi

Comment: I tried with RequirePkce true but didn’t worked. again set RequirePkce to false and set origin with client url in ClientCorsOrigins table. And then started working...

Comment: any idea about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110492/how-to-logout-user-from-a-particular-session-identity-server-4-net-core

Comment: @ravi perfect! happy it fixed ur issue. yes cors is needed cause you are calling the idp from the spa app  - I will take a look on other issue

Comment: Thank you :) your answer gave a direction to resolve. Can you update your answer so that I can mark it correct?

Comment: @Ravi I added the cors in the response, also provided you a link to a working sample, I still think `RequirePkce` should be true, this is suggested in the official docs too https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html?highlight=RequirePkce#interactive-clients

Comment: yeh but don't why not working when making PKCE true. Anyway. Did you get a chance to look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110492/how-to-logout-user-from-a-particular-session-identity-server-4-net-core ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the tokens using the authorization code flow, you need to pass the following details:

```
        client_id = "authcodeflowclient",       //Id of this client
        client_secret = "mysecret",
        grant_type = "authorization_code",
        code_verifier = code_verifier,
        code = code,
        redirect_uri = "https://localhost:5001/CodeFlow/callback"
```

When you set the secret, you need to hash it,using

```
            ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
            {
                new Secret
                {
                    Value = "mysecret".Sha512()
                }
            },
```

As you are using the authorization code flow, you should make sure this is set to

AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

Does that help?

Comment: passed client_secret but "getting Client secret validation failed for client: angular_app_client_id."

Comment: you need to pass the secret as defined in IdentityServer for that client. what does your client definition look like?

Comment: below are the entries for this client in table
client_id = angular_app_client_id,
client_name = Angular App,
grant_type = client_credentials, authorization_code,
client_secret = vUULtAFUN8HBNhs2Qft9yJUvTPnPfrtbVwF8/KdeXSI=

Comment: why do you need both grant types? just curious.

Comment: actually on server code using https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4/src/Models/GrantTypes.cs#L22 | if have only authorization_code still not working

Comment: I would post the complete client definition code + a copy of the initial request that fails (use Fiddler to  capture it) and update the question.

Comment: Updated the description. Please check