# Allow single session per user IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

With IdentityServer4 I need to allow a single user session per time. If the user authenticates with device A and then with B, session and access token must be invalidated for A and, even better, client A could receive a notification that user has logged out in a second step.The main thing is making the server force invalidate session and token. There are similar questions, one of them redirects us to the following link:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/736

where it is explained to use backchannel logout and in the login method of the identity server to obtain the previous IdentityServer sessionID that should have been persisted somewhere. Then I should send logout tokens to all clients.

Another solution is given here
[How to Logout user from a particular session Identity Server 4, .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110492/how-to-logout-user-from-a-particular-session-identity-server-4-net-core)

telling us to use an ITicketStore implementation to be able to invalidate the session.

The configuration used is IdentityServer4 with authorizaton code flow with PKCE. Which approach is best for my case? Is there another approach where I could simply delete the access token in the id server database?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case probably a combination of both. In our real-world implementation we combine server-side storage of sessions via `ITicketStore` (stored in a custom database with sessions linked to user accounts and also storing the list of client IDs for each session) with the ability to trigger back-channel logout of any session at any time (i.e. not just via the default user-triggered mechanism).

In our case we do this to be able to invalidate sessions for other reasons (e.g. password or other security setting changes, a "log me out of everything" feature, impersonation rights being revoked etc) but this approach could form the foundation of a "single session per user" feature should you wish.